# How to auto update your software with every new release?

Tags: git, updates, open-source, release

I am currently developing software for a client from open source. I made a few changes in the code and it was working fine. The client wanted to get the software to a point where he can install it on the desktop. So I repackaged the software, create an installer and send the software to him. Now he wants the software connected to the download server so that when you have a new release it will auto-update.
I am stuck at this point as I really don't understand where to start or how to google this problem. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, but this kind of broad "where do I start" question isn't very well suited to this site's format - you need something more like a traditional discussion forum, where you can chat back and forth about what you're trying to do, what the options might be, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some directions, here is one of the way

As its desktop based installation, you can simply create a PowerShell script and pass to the client. That script will check and install the software as per his convenience.

He can setup the script in Windows scheduler to check multiple times a day.

(so now you can google - How do I install an application using PowerShell? or something similar)